# How do link up a different set of view from table view?

Tags: iphone

Hi there i'm currently doing a project that requires my app to transition from a table view to a different view. For example my table view has 4 item and what i'm trying to do is have a different set of detail view. I would like to have a scroll view in it which has different content for each of the items. Right now i'm only able to pass in an image or text/label. I really need help for this.

Comment: what've you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use Model-view controller technique... keep all related info in a class(model) when you tap on the  tableviewCell pass that model to the detailed view.